# From and to spans update in right order to avoid intersect conflict on previous values

Tags: c#, range, constraints, intersect

So I have a list giving some age ranges like so:

```
[{ From: 0, To: 3, Name: "baby"},
{ From: 4, To: 17, Name: "child"},
{ From: 18, To: 64, Name: "adult"},
{ From: 65, To: 99, Name: "senior"}]
```

If I wish to manipulate the age ranges and update them I would loop through each of the object and update up to our database. The only thing is, when doing this we have a constraint in our database to make sure no age ranges intersect each other. This will happen as soon as I change for example the first objects `To` property to `5` and the second objects `From` property to `6`, because we haven't updated the second object yet.

While this is legal when the whole update is finish, it´s not legal when I´m looping through each object and update them one by one.

Right now I don't know the most effective way to do this other than brute force through, update each object and if it fails re add it to an update list and keep doing that until there is none left. But I'm sure there are a smarter way.

So is there some way to determine what object should be first updated according to either its original value or some checkups to the next and previous object in the list?

Programming language does not really matter here since I'm trying to get the logic behind it, but I'm using C#.

[Graph of blocks collide on update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxocG.png)
In the graphic provided here is just an example of how an update could be.

UPDATE:

We went from doing just single updates to doing multiple updates in a partial view so that's why we ran into this problem.

[Screenshot of the modal that is responsible for the data that is being sent to the action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwtKd.jpg)

So its just a fairly simple action looping through the objects and then using the update method that calls an stored procedure in our oracle database.

```
public ActionResult Update(VmPersonAge model){
     try {
          conn.Open();
          foreach (var personAge in model.PersonAges) {
               personAge.Update(conn);
          }
     } finally {
          conn.Close();
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Tickets");
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I have one solution for this issue but its just not pretty. so I have this method to use in the action that just loops through and if it fails it adds it to a new list and retry afterwards until there is none left but again its not pretty nor the right way to do it.

```cs
private void UpdatePersonAges(List<CPersonAge> PersonAges, OracleConnection Conn){
     List<CPersonAge> updateList = new List<CPersonAge>();
     foreach (var personAge in PersonAges)
     {
          try
          {
               personAge.Update(Conn);
          }
          catch
          {
               updateList.Add(personAge);
          }
     }
     if (updateList.Any())
     {
          UpdatePersonAges(updateList, Conn);
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you have written so far? This sounds like a class question so just giving you answer is inappropriate. We can give specific pointers and suggestions if we have **your** actual code to work with.

Comment: If your database schema doesn't rely on the IDs of the age range items, then a relatively simple solution is to delete all of the items in the table and re-insert them.

Comment: @DanielDearlove I see your point, its work related though :)
The code is fairly simple as the data is coming from HTML form in an MVC razor page. then this action just loops through all the objects in the list and using the update method that calls the database and just throws exception if failed.

updated my question since writing code blocks in comments is not pretty. :)

Comment: @JackA. sadly we have a price attached to this "age id" for a specific age on a specific ticket so that would not be possible unless I would update the prices for each age as well. :)

Comment: If the order is not allowed to be changed, then do the contractions first. You're guaranteed to have at least one (when "outer" part of terminal intervals being pushed out, it doesn't count as expansion). Then radiate from each contraction to the both sides using breadth-first approach. It should work. If the order can change, then it's a different story.

Comment: Actually. Obviously, you're not guaranteed to have a contraction if nothing is being contracted. My bad. If that's the case, you can pick any interval as a starting point.

Comment: Since you're using Oracle, another possible simple solution is to use a transaction with `SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10003.htm

Comment: @SergeyKrusch seems like a valid solution. in this case we have the age span of 0-100 then divided into multiple age groups baby, child, adult and senior. Multiple groups could come in later but should really not matter. Then one would at least contract to make space for one of the other groups.
Never used the breadth-first approach so have to look into that.

Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @Aquilay you are welcome. Although I would personally go with the solution that Jack is suggesting.